# Node error in citusdb

Tags: postgresql, citus

I am getting a node error when tiring to create a shard.

```
SELECT * from master_create_empty_shard('customer_reviews');
Error: could only find 0 of 2 possible nodes error in citusdb
```

same error was getting for the following also.

```
\STAGE customer_reviews FROM '/home/ubuntu/customer_reviews_1998.csv' (FORMAT CSV)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified `pg_worker_list.conf` in the `$PGDATA` directory? This file should contain a list of worker nodes that will be used to store the data.

This error usually occurs when the master is trying to find enough nodes to write the data to, but cannot find them in the worker list file.

Comment: What about the "add node" command instead? `psql -h localhost -p 5439 -c "SELECT * FROM master_add_node('localhost', 5439);" dbname` Or do we need both? The `pg_worker_list.conf` file and the `SELECT` command.